# Can't interact with database when published to azure

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, azure

Below is the steps i have took to publish my Website to Azure. I have two data connections the "defaultconnection" for users tables log in register etc. The other is a connection to an Azure Sql Database.

1. On Azure i created a new app service.
2. In Visual Studio i click on project and select publish.
3. In the publish Web window that pops up i select Microsoft Azure Web Apps.
4. In the following window i select the app service i created in Azure.
5. In the settings window it shows the two connection database connections.

They both have the same connection string which is the Azure hosted Database. I am not sure what to change the connection string to for the users table. I created a SQL database in azure and connected that to the app service then used that connection string for the "defaultconnection". The string is below

```
Server=tcp:userauthen.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=userauthen.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=USERAUTH;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I published to azure and am able to go through the pages but as soon as i try to interact with the database i get an internal server error 500.

I tried publishing the website without userlogin so i could see if it connected to the Azure sql database but i still get the internal server error 500. I am really stuck at this point and any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i changed the firewall settings to allow certain IP address and it worked. I can access both my databases.